# c# asp store variable between refresh for only 1 tab/page

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, session-variables, page-refresh

I have a situation where a user can open more than 1 tab or page to pull up different reports.  When they pull up the report from a.aspx I pass the data to b.aspx via a session variable and it loads b.aspx just fine.  The problem I am having is that since the session variable exists across all the pages if they hit refresh on any of the report pages, copies of b.aspx, they get the latest report they tried to open from a.aspx.  How can I have a session variable or possibly a GET or POST upon refresh of b.aspx that only stays for that particular b.aspx?  Right now on the calling page a.aspx.cs

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["CHART"] = "chartname";
```

And on the receiving page b.aspx.cs,

```
string chart = HttpContext.Current.Session["CHART"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Querystring** for this instead of session. It looks like you are just passing a string value (chartname) to the other page. You won't have the problem with refresh with querystrings.

So pass it as b.aspx?Chart="chartname".

Comment: And then read the value on b.aspx with `string chartname=Request.QueryString["chartname"]`. Obviously you'll want to make sure the query string contains chartname before trying to read it.

Comment: @msm8bball QueryString["Chart"]

Comment: Ah yes, It would be `string chartname=Request.QueryString["Chart"]` because that is the name of the query string parameter being passed. Good catch @JustinRyder

Comment: @msm8bball QueryString["chartname"] would get the value associated with b.aspx?chartname=someValue. "chartname" was the value in the answerer's example, not the key.